# Gmail script - auto forward and change sender?

Tags: gwt, scripting, gmail, gmail-api, sender

I am trying to write a script that's gonna automaticaly forward a received email but at the same time change the sender (Gmail forwards messages with original sender).
I have already tried the .forward function, but wasn't really able to change the sender.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the [Managing Aliases](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/alias_and_signature_settings) documentation. You must [create](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/create) aliases prior to use. In some cases, users must also verify ownership of the alias. Aliases for external addresses should send mail through a remote SMTP mail sending agent (MSA). To configure the SMTP MSA for an alias, use the `smtpMsa` field to provide the connection details.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48627685/4829915) is correct that you must create aliases first.

But if you agree to settle on something less strict, as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#forward(String,Object)), you can just use the advanced parameters `name` and `replyTo`:

```
var alt_name = 'Different name';
var reply_to = 'fake@address.com';
var to='recepient@gmail.com';
var obj = {replyTo: message.getFrom(), name: alt_name};
message.forward(recepient, obj);
```